# Customizing Day Cell content in FullCalendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using **fullcalendar** with react. I am trying to customize the `dayGrid` view. According to the [Content Injection docs for react](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react#content-injection) I can use custom content for the rendering of both the date and the header cells. The [dayCellContent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-cell-render-hooks) "hook" states that:

> Generated content is inserted inside the inner-most wrapper of the day cell. It does not replace the  cell.

I've provided an implementation for the `dayCellContent` and noticed that my content gets injected into the following structure:

```
<td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-wed fc-day-past rot_time-off_day-cell" data-date="2021-04-07">
    <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
        <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top">
            <a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">
                ...custom content goes here
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events"></div>
        <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Now, the problem is that this structure lets you insert content **ONLY in the upper right corner** of the date cell due to the positioning of the element. Furthermore, it is in an anchor element.

Example:

```
function renderDayCell(dayCellContent: DayCellContentArg) {
    return (
        <div>
            {dayCellContent.dayNumberText}
        </div>
    );
}
```

[image]

Is there a clean way to customize the whole content of the cell somehow? I've seen a couple of sites using **fullcalendar** that have their content inserted directly into the `td`. Not sure if this is version dependent or they're using the alternative JS approach based on `domNodes` or `html`. I am using version `5.6.0` of fullcalendar.

Comment: It's possible you could use a Background event which covers the whole cell

Comment: Okay, that partially solves the problem. How can I modify the full content of the data cell header, though (the part containing the current date or `fc-daygrid-day-top` from the structure mentioned above?

Comment: The bit containing the date is modifiable separately - either the date format option or the day header render hooks might be what you need. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-display

Comment: I am indeed already using the `dayCellContent` to modify the day cell. The problem is, like I pointed out in the example above, that the content gets injected inside a nested anchor so I don't have access to the whole "header" of the cell where the number is located but only the most right portion of it due to the inlining of the `a` element. For example, I can't put anything in the left-most part where the number is located.

Comment: I said day **header** content, not day cell content. Look at the documentation link I gave you, it lists all the options. You asked about changing where the date is located, the header is where you do that. The header, in fullCalendar terminology, is the bit that says "Fri" in your picture.

Comment: If you mean the bit to the left of the day number, that's slightly different. What exactly do you want to put in there anyway? And couldn't you achieve it already with a background event? I'm on mobile right not so I can't test anything myself, so apologies if I'm being imprecise

Comment: @ADyson I want to style the whole upper portion of the day cell (the full width of it) (where the day number is located) and add elements to it. I was just curious how can I do that because the approach in the docs lets you customize only the right-most part where the day number is located but I've noticed a few websites using the fullcalendar where the structure is quite simplified and they include their content right into the `td` element so they have full control over the cell content.

Comment: OP, were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: @Alex Uh, no. I see 2 approaches. You either have to use an older version of the library (which have a simpler structure) or do manual manipulations to the element structure. Both cases are not a good idea but the library design regarding this point is just bad, I guess.

Comment: Uh okay. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement although not using React. I solved it using a manual manipulation of the DOM elements as suggested above. I have used jQuery for the select and manipulation. It is posted here in case anyone would like to see an example of how this can be achieved using DOM manipulation.

I implemented `dayCellContent` to make the day-cell DOM element easily identifiable by wrapping it in a `span`, with a unique `id` attribute based on the day of year number:

```
dayCellContent: function(info, create) {
    const element = create('span', { id: "fc-day-span-"+info.date.getDayOfYear() }, info.dayNumberText);
    return element;
},
```

This `dayCellContent` implementation makes no visible difference to the calendar but makes it easier to identify the elements to be modified in the DOM.

I then implemented `dayCellDidMount` to do the DOM manipulation by finding the appropriate cells and selecting their parent’s parent:

```
dayCellDidMount: function(info) {
    let element = "<div style='position: absolute; left: 4px; top: 4px;'><a href='https://www.w3schools.com/'>TEST-"+info.dayNumberText+"</a></div>";
    $('#fc-day-span-'+info.date.getDayOfYear()).parent().parent().prepend(element);
},
```

In this case I have just put a link to w3c in the top left of the cell with test text which also includes the day number. It results in cells that look like this:

[image]

Clearly the CSS could be improved and should be moved out to the CSS definitions but it illustrates the point.

**Warning:** This approach makes assumptions about the DOM structure that [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io) generates. The generated HTML may change in future versions of the product which could invalidate it. If you go this way then be careful when doing a FullCalendar update.

Note that the getDayOfYear function is from the ext-all.js library. Any way of uniquely identifying the day will work.

Comment: You should be careful using `.getMonth()).parent().parent().prepend(element);`. They might change the structure of the component and you might be left with a broken code if you update. You should hardcode the version of the library or inspect the code every time you update it.

Comment: I agree. We will have to be careful with the versioning. Given the difficulty with getting access via the approved API, I cannot see another way at the moment. If you can see another way then I would be grateful if you could post it. I will update the post to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

ngAfterViewInit(){
// Your CSS as text
var styles =`.fc td, .fc th { vertical-align: top; padding: 0; height: 100px; } a{ color:#3d1cba; }`

```
let styleSheet = document.createElement("style");
styleSheet.innerText = styles;
document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);


let arrTD = document.querySelectorAll('td.fc-timeline-slot');
let arrTR= document.querySelectorAll('td.fc-timeline-lane.fc-resource');
let arrInject= document.querySelectorAll('td.fc-timeline-lane.fc-resource>div.fc-timeline-lane-frame');
console.log(arrTR);

let k=-1;
arrTR.forEach(eachTR => {
    let i=1;
    let str = '';
    k++;

    let data_resource_id= eachTR.getAttribute('data-resource-id');
    console.log(data_resource_id);

    arrTD.forEach(eachTD => {          
        let  k=100*(i-1);
        i=i+1;
        let data_date= eachTD.getAttribute('data-date');
        console.log(data_date);

        let data_resource_id= eachTR.getAttribute('data-resource-id'); 
        console.log(data_resource_id);

        str = str + '<span data-date="'+data_date+'" data-resource-id="'+data_resource_id+'" class="plus_icon" style="position:relative;top: 0px; left: '+k+'px !important;width:500px;height:500px;z-index:3;-moz-border-radius:100px;border:1px  solid #ddd;-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px  #fff;">+</span>';          
  
     
  });
    arrInject[k].innerHTML=str;

});


let elementList = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('span.plus_icon');
for(let i=0;i<elementList.length;i++){   
 elementList[i].addEventListener('click', this.plusClick.bind(this));
}
```

}